# Custom administrator in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to create the admin group which can have create/update/delete the user as well as audit/view report permission in alfresco 5.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS" groups to which the default "admin" belongs - the admin can add other users to this group. You can see this group if you go to the Admin Tools -> Groups page, tick the "Show System Groups" checkbox in the top right corner and click the "Browse" button.

Users added to this group will be "full" admins though and will have access to more than just the actions you've described. So you should grant users these permissions with caution.

Comment: Thanks.I don't need full access instead need to create separate group for create/update/delete the user as well as audit/view report permission